# prove inequality $x-y<\tan x-\tan y<4(x-y)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

$x-y < \tan x - \tan y < 4(x-y)$. How to prove that inequality? If $\frac{-\pi}{3} < y < x < \frac{\pi}{3}$. Do I need to use Lagrange theorem? If yes how it should look like? I ve tried but I don’t understand logic of that prove and theorem

Answer (score 1):

$$x-y<\tan(x)-\tan(y)<4(x-y)\iff1<\frac{\tan(x)-\tan(y)}{x-y}<4.$$By the Mean Value Theorem, $$\frac{\tan(x)-\tan(y)}{x-y}=1+\tan^2(c),$$for some $c\in\left(-\frac\pi3,\frac\pi3\right)$. Since in that interval one always has $1\leqslant\tan^2<4$, this almost proves what you want to prove. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

The right inequality.

Since $\sin(x-y)\leq x-y$, $\cos{x}\geq\frac{1}{2}$ and $\cos{y}\geq\frac{1}{2},$we obtain:
$$\frac{\tan{x}-\tan{y}}{x-y}=\frac{\sin(x-y)}{(x-y)\cos{x}\cos{y}}\leq\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}=4.$$

The left inequality.

Let $f(x)=\tan{x}-x,$ where $x\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$.

Thus, $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}-1=\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}\geq0,$$
which says $f(x)>f(y)$ and we are done!